# Android 4: Give buttons another style/appearance

Tags: java, android

I'd like to change the appearance of the default Android 4 buttons. They look like that:

[image]

I'd like them to be completely black, a white border, no rounded corners, that's all. The blue hover effect is great, no change to that. Unfortunately, there are a lot of parameters that button has. Can I realize that with a single style.xml? Which are the interesting parameters?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Button Style:
style.xml

```
<style name="Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/txt_size_medium</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/btn_txt_selector</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

btn.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:centerColor="@color/btn_focused_center" android:endColor="@color/btn_focused_end" android:startColor="@color/btn_focused_start" />

            <corners android:radius="@dimen/radious_btn" />

            <padding android:bottom="@dimen/padding_bottom_btn" android:left="@dimen/padding_left_btn" android:right="@dimen/padding_right_btn" android:top="@dimen/padding_top_btn" />

            <stroke android:width="@dimen/border_width_btn" android:color="@color/btn_focused_border" />
        </shape></item>

    <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient android:angle="270" android:centerColor="@color/btn_normal_center" android:endColor="@color/btn_normal_end" android:startColor="@color/btn_normal_start" />

            <corners android:radius="@dimen/radious_btn" />

            <padding android:bottom="@dimen/padding_bottom_btn" android:left="@dimen/padding_left_btn" android:right="@dimen/padding_right_btn" android:top="@dimen/padding_top_btn" />

            <stroke android:width="@dimen/border_width_btn" android:color="@color/btn_normal_border" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

btn_txt_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/btn_txt_focused"></item>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/btn_txt_selected"></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/btn_txt_disabled"></item>
    <item android:color="@color/btn_txt_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

Comment: Thank you so far. Can you tell me what are the root elements of btn.xml and btn_text_selector, getting xml errors when putting <resources> around them. Do both files belong to the values or layout folder? Thanks again

Comment: i've update my answer, both those files are belongs to drawable, and root element is <selector>

Comment: thx, but all attribute values in btn.xml/btn_txt_selector.xml like @dimen/radious_btn are unknown. So I have to declare them first, right?